# how to take the first column of an excel table in matlab

Tags: excel, loops, matlab, for-loop

I have the following code and it takes the column with the sequence of numbers (1...through 122) instead of my 122 values that are in column A of the excel sheet. Why is that happening? Because of the "length" function I use? How to make the loop take the actual values from column A? And how to save the output of the 122 calculations in another Excel table.
My "function" has two inputs.

```
for i = 1:length('/data/mri_analysis/spreadsheet.xlsx');
    example_of_a_function(i,0.12);        
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to store the data that you read from the spreadsheet in a variable:

```
myTable = readtable('/data/mri_analysis/spreadsheet.xlsx');
```

This gives you a [MATLAB table](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html). You'll need to check that the table you get contains the data you expect, and maybe specify different options to `readtable` if necessary. For example, does the spreadsheet have a header row with the names of the columns? Are all the values in the column you want numeric, or are some of them text or missing?

Then you need to use your loop index variable `i` to access the data in the table one value at a time. As shown in the question, your loop runs once for each letter in the text '/data/mri_analysis/spreadsheet.xlsx', which probably isn't what you meant. You need something like:

```
for i = 1:height(myTable)
    example_function(myTable.(1)(i));
end
```

`myTable.(1)(i)` gives you the value in the *i*-th row of column 1 of `myTable`. If your spreadsheet has a header row with column names and you let `readtable` use those column names as the table variable names, then you can use the slightly nicer form

```
myTable.FirstColumn(i)
```

It sounds like you're very new to programming, so I recommend working through some of the examples from MATLAB's help to make sure you understand what is going on.